# unpivoting data in powerbi power quiery to achieve the defined format

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[image: Input]

In power queries I am trying to achieve a table like below:

[image]

How do I achieve it?

I Tried multiple ways but didn't get any result

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"From Date", type text}, {"To Date", type text}, {"SKU", type text}, {"UOM", type text}, {"CP", type text}, {"SP", type text}, {"UOM_1", type text}, {"CP_2", type text}, {"SP_3", type text}, {"UOM_4", type text}, {"CP_5", type text}, {"SP_6", type text}}),
leading=3, groupsof=3,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(    #"Changed Type" , "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames( #"Changed Type"),leading+groupsof)),
#"First Row" = List.Distinct(List.RemoveNulls(Record.FieldValues(Source{0}))),
Repeat=List.Repeat(#"First Row",Table.RowCount(Source)-2),
combine=Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns( #"Split Column by Delimiter")&{Repeat},Table.ColumnNames(#"Split Column by Delimiter")&{"Customer"})
in combine
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it but I need UOM, CP, and SP in the column how do I work out?

Comment: No idea what that means, sorry. With the sample data shown, UOM CP and SP are in a column.   If you don't like that, post real sample data as text, not images, along with sample text showing desired output.  Your question is hard to understand

Comment: Added an output image